# How do I recover a deleted Views display?

Tags: 7, views

I installed a module (FAQ) which provides multiple Views displays, which are based in code. I accidentally removed the master display, and am left with the various block and page displays also created by the module.

Is there any way to retrieve/recover the master display, short of removing/reinstalling the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To revert the whole view back to what the faq module provides by default:

1. Go to the views listing (admin/structure/views).
2. Click the little arrow next to "Edit" in the operations column.
3. Click the "Revert" link.
4. Click the "Revert" button.

Comment: This Answer is refering to Drupal 7 correct? How would this been done in D8?